# SQL Server query, simillar to Symmetrical Difference in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geoprocessing, sql-server

i have two tables with geometry data in SQL Server. How can I get all geometry differences with spatial query? I tried:

```
select k.geom.STSymDifference(r.geom).ToString() from table1 k, table2 r
```

But it returns to many rows. I would like to get same result as I get it if I use Symmetrical Difference function in ArcMap.

Comment: It's not clear where you are currently facing the problem. How many geometries does each table have? The query you are running, will calculate the Symmetric difference between each pairs of geometries from both the tables.

Comment: table1 has 95 records, table2 has 48 records, result in sql server is 4560 records. If I use function Symmetrical Difference  in ArcGIS, result is 46 records!

Comment: Well, you do a `CROSS JOIN` so you get exactly what you're asking for: 48*95=4560. What you need is a `WHERE` clause that will exclude the rows you don't want.

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how to form where statement. Query I'm looking for should return all polygons from table1 MINUS polygons from table2.